# how to select element in selenium by custom identifier

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium with python for parsing page.
I have a HTML page with this markup:

```html
    <body>
        <div my-id="article-3">some text</div>
        <div my-id="article-4">some text1</div>
    </body>
```

And I need to specify not only the value, but also the name:

```py
    divs = driver.find_element_by_id('article-3')
```

Because `my-id="article-3"` is not `id="article-3"`.

How to set custom id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the CSS selector.

```
div = driver.find_element_by_css_locator('div[my-id="article-3"]')
```